# Is there a way to automatically "append" a string to a file name, that already exists, in s3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I'm using DigitalOcean to store user uploaded files. My upload function looks like this:

```
static uploadFileToRemoteStorage(data, config) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const params = {
                ACL: 'public-read',
                Bucket: 'some-bucket', // pass your bucket name
                Key: process.env.ROOT_DOMAIN + '/' + config.name, 
                Body: data,
                ContentType: config.mimetype
            };
            s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
                if (s3Err) {
                    reject(s3Err)
                }
                console.log('data.location', data.Location)
                resolve({
                    url: data.Location
                })

            });
        })
    }
```

I was wondering, how to automatically append some number, to an already existing file name(might not be the same actual file though). For example, let's say a user has already uploaded a file named "**cat.jpg**". An additional upload of a file with the same name, should be stored as **cat(1).jpg**.

Does s3 expose such an option? If not, what alternative way would you recommend?

Comment: s3 doesn't do such a thing - it will just overwrite the file. So your best bet is to get all the files that match the pattern your after first and then work out what the next number in the sequence yours should use is.

Comment: A common technique is to upload files to an unique name ([GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), then map that name to a 'friendly' name in a database. For example, imagine how many same-named files there would be in Dropbox. They clearly do not store files under their original filename.

Comment: Yes this is more or less what i did.